# rename the get_field_display in django serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

i am trying to use the get_field_display function in Django in my serializer but I want to rename it to something else(consider it worker_role).
what should I do?

```
class AdminUnsubscriberListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    worker_role= "get_role_display"
```

and the model is :

```
 class Worker(models.Model):
     ROLE_OPTIONS= [
    ("AD", _("admin")),
    ("WO", _("Worker")),]

        role= models.CharField(
            choices=ROLE_OPTIONS,
            null=True,
            blank=True,
            default=None,
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write it as
`worker_role = serializers.CharField(source="get_role_display")`

also it supports nested lookups for example

`worker_role = serializers.CharField(source="worker.get_role_display")`